# NetBeans Autocomplete JavaFX CSS

Tags: css, maven, javafx, netbeans, autocomplete

i programmed a Program with JavaFX recently.

Now im trying to optimize the optics a bit with CSS.
After i finally figured out, how to add CSS to the Program, NetBeans still doesnt show me Autocompletion for it.

So my first Steps were normal CSS, which obviously doesnt work.

Its a Maven-Project, made with the JavaFX FXML Maven Archetype.

I tried some solutions, but none worked. One Solution was to make a new Ant-JavaFX-Project, do the CSS in there and copy it back. But not only this is really dirty, i cant even create the Project, cause NetBeans says, my Java 14.0.1 SDK doesnt fit it, while it does in the Maven-Project...

Any Solutions? Here a Pic of the not working autocomplete:

[image: https://puu.sh/G5zpV/8b958167fc.png]

The Project itself compiles with no Problems..

Comment: It might not fix the issue but are you using the latest version of Netbeans?

Comment: 12.0, so yea. Newest Maven too